# JQuery validation plugin radio buttons "error display" when not valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, radio-button, label

I'm using Jquery validation plugin to check if a radio is checked before submitting my form, it's working just fine..

My problem is in the way the error message is displayed, I know that the plugin uses the  tag to show the error message for each input. But I'm already using the label tag for these radio element as follows :

```
<label><input type="radio" name="A2-3" value="Oui"> Oui </label>
```

(to be able to check the radio by clicking on the word)

So when the radio isn't checked and the error message is added, all is messed up like the picture bellow: 
[image]

the message should appear under the two choices

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validation errorPlacement option

An example:

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6rGX5/5/

html to display errors

```
<div class="form_field">
  <div class="error_message_holder"></div>
  <!-- your text field goes here -->
  <label>Field Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="required" name="..." ...>
</div>

<!-- you can have other elements similar to above -->
```

and javascript

```
$('form').validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.html('your error message here');
    if(element.closest('.form_field').find('label.error').length == 0){
      error.insertBefore( element.closest('.form_field').find('.error_message_holder') );
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the solution I was looking for :). But now the error message doesn't go away automatically when I check the radio. Do you have an idea how to solve that ?

Comment: but the success function is only called when All the form is valid ! I need it to go away once the user checks the radio (that's how it originally worked)

Comment: errorPlacement should work fine and automatically hides the error message once you enter text/select radio etc. I guess you are doing something else wrong. please check.

Comment: See the updated post - it works just fine. JS fiddle included to test

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `errorElement` option to specify the type of element to wrap around the input when reporting an error. Or you can use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options to provide functions of your own that add and remove error notices.

Comment: I tested the errorElement with span, div and em and none of them gave a proper display. Thank's for your answer anyway.